# ASP.NET - accessing ViewBag in a View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I have a one page that uses Javascript to load several PartialViews. I am trying to access ViewBag in some Javascript but am having problems.

MyView:

```
<div>
  <script>
    var test = @ViewBag.test;
    alert(test);
  </script>
</div>
```

The controller which handles this view:

```
public PartialViewResult MyView()
{
  ViewBag.test = "test";
  return PartialView();
}
```

When I run it, the Javascript alert does not appear. I get a "Conditional compilation is turned off" highlight under the View's calling of ViewBag.

Comment: check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your view is rendered, this is what is produced:

```
var test = test;
```

..that is obviously not valid javascript.

You need to enclose it in quotes:

```
var test = "@ViewBag.test";
```

Which produces:

```
var test = "test";
```

..valid Javascript.