# Mixing tag helpers and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm using MVC 6 along with [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net). I'd like to know if it's possible to mix tag helpers and jQuery code, something like this (it's not working right now):

```
$('#add-row').on('click', function () {
    table.row.add([
        '<select asp-for="ItemID" asp-items="ViewBag.Items" class="form-control input-sm"></select>',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm">X</button>'
    ]).draw(false);
});
```

My goal is to add a row to a given table with a dropdown inside of it. which takes its data from a `ViewBag` object created in the controller. You can realize that the actual problem is to use tag helpers and jQuery code in the `<script>` section.

Comment: In general JS\Jquery can't take any data from the ViewBag since it's rendered in the server side.
But it might be possible to save the `ViewBag.Items` into a local JS variable and then manipulate it.

Comment: ah.. maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file) will help

Comment: The problem is not the ViewBag, but the asp-for and asp-items attributes. The line `<select asp-for="ItemID" asp-items="ViewBag.Items" class="form-control input-sm"></select>` should be rendered as a standard HTML select control, with `option` elements inside of it, according to the items inside of the ViewBag.

Comment: this is also rendered to standard html as well. you can read [this](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/18/mvc6-select-tag-helper.aspx)., so you can do it yourself by just taking the data from the ViewBag and creating it manually using jquery.