# How to use @ViewBag value in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to use ViewBag value in JQuery.  Does anyone provide me some idea how to do that.

```
//My code

    <label>Cost<span id="spCost">@ViewBag.Cost</span></label>

//JQuery

var original = $("#spCost").val;
```

I also tried:

```
var original = '@ViewBag.Cost';
```

But, currently, it is showing no value in `original`.

Please help me.

Comment: labels doesn't support .val. You need to use .text() to extract the value.

Comment: @DinoMyte, I am not getting the value. It is showing `' '`.

Comment: have you tried : $("#spCost").text() ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but getting `' '`.

Comment: look here then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file

Comment: @DinoMyte, I tried all the solutions provided there but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of your view, write something similar to this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var original = @ViewBag.Cost;
alert(original);
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var original = @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Cost); 
alert("Text is: " + original.Text);
</script>
```

or if you want to use the viewbag value in a separate .js file, then create a js file something similar to this

```
var newJSFile = (function(my){
   my.CostFromView = 0;
   //Your code
}(newJSFile || {}));
```

and then at the end of your view,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
newJSFile.CostFromView = @ViewBag.Cost;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var val = parseInt(@ViewBag.Cost);
</script>
```