# How to get the value of a ViewBag with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am passing a ViewBag with "error" value when the user does not complete the form, and with jquery I am placing the ViewBag in an alert so that the user can see the message. But I do not get any results.

Also, I understand that the GET and POST in .net are 2 different pages, the GET shows the View and the POST returns to show the View but with the validated data. In my opinion, I see that actually only one page is displayed, since I have put an alert () to determine if it is true and when the page loads the message appears, but when I press the submit button, the message does not appear again.

**View**

```
@model wsCharlas.Models.ClsPrueba

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Prueba";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Prueba</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ClsPrueba</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id_prueba, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.id_prueba, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.id_prueba, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nombre_prueba, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.nombre_prueba, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.nombre_prueba, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

       alert("Hello World");        

       if ('@ViewBag.msg' != "") {
            alert('@ViewBag.msg');
       }
    });


</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Prueba()
    {
        return View(new ClsPrueba());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Prueba(ClsPrueba prueba)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.msg = "error";
            return View(prueba);
        }

        return View(prueba);
    }
```

Comment: jajajajaja... saludos bro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a work around for you. Its a quick one taken from 
[Possible to access MVC ViewBag object from Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file)

in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="customInput" data-value = "@ViewBag.CustomValue" />
```

in JS

```
var customVal = $("#customInput").data("value");
```

You can go and upvote the answer there.

Comment: kind of overkill to use a data attribute to do it... just use `value="@ViewBag.msg"` then in the script call `$("customInput").val()`. not a big difference but keep it simple :)