# Passing Parameter Name to DropDownList Inside `` (back-tic or grave accent)

Tags: jquery, razor, dropdownlistfor

Inside my cshtml and my script, I have the following loop that works:

```
              for (var i = 0; i < xValue.length; i++) {
                var obj = xValue[i];

                if (obj.NameOfViewData.slice(0, obj.NameOfViewData.indexOf("_")) == $("#SeriesTypeId option:selected").text().replace(" ", "")) {
                    console.log(obj.NameOfViewData);
                    console.log(obj.NameOfViewData.slice(0, obj.NameOfViewData.indexOf("_")));

                    var iname = "Pt_ReturnType";

                    $(container).append(`<div class="input" id=td` + iCnt + `_` + i + ` ` +
                        `value="Drops Element ` + iCnt + `_` + i + `">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TagValueName, ViewData["Pt_ReturnType"] as SelectList, "--" + "testing" + "--")</div>`);

                }
            }
```

However, when I try to change the ViewData to receive my string var with the same name, it does not work. What I tried (idea from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```
$(container).append(`<div class="input" id=td` + iCnt + `_` + i + ` ` +
                                `value="Drops Element ` + iCnt + `_` + i + `">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TagValueName, ViewData[`${iname}`] as SelectList, "--" + "testing" + "--")</div>`);
```

(this one "breaks" the HTML page)

I also tried:

```
$(container).append(`<div class="input" id=td` + iCnt + `_` + i + ` ` +
                            `value="Drops Element ` + iCnt + `_` + i + `">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TagValueName, ViewData[iname] as SelectList, "--" + "testing" + "--")</div>`);
```

(This one, it does not recognize "iname as variable")

Please, notice that I am using ` and not ". The reason of that is in a previous question that I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227324/returning-viewbag-inside-html-dropdownlistfor-inside-single-quotes/57229298#57229298).

Comment: That's not how Razor syntax works, unfortunately. The @Html parts are evaluated on the server, and ` is not valid, there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read more on [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

You don't need to concatenate when using back ticks. You can use placeholders.

```
$(container).append(`<div class="input" id="td${iCnt}_${i}" value="Drops Element ${iCnt}_${i}">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TagValueName, ViewData["Pt_ReturnType"] as SelectList, "--" + "testing" + "--")</div>`);
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, however, my problem is passing the parameter to the ViewData part and not before. For the "iCnts" and the "i" I am being able to pass data. If I try the same approach ViewData[${iname}, it does not recognize as my var.

Comment: You can't. It needs to be defined in your razor template and not javascript because your razor template and javascript code are two separate entities.