# MVC Url Helper with Javascript variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following MVC Url Helper:

```
 var result = $(this).val();

 var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.WpActionUrl((object)@ViewBag.Org_ID, "DocumentList", "MP", (object)result,null, null))';
```

The problem that I am experiencing is that the code will not recognize"result" in the MVC Url Helper.

I tried to delimit the single quote but no luck.

```
 var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.WpActionUrl((object)@ViewBag.Org_ID, "DocumentList", "MP", (object) ' + result + ',null, null))';
```

Comment: You cannot use a value known only in JavaScript, client-side, in code that runs server-side.

Comment: @Amy I am trying to just update the url so it an accept it. This is all in the View so not sure why it would not be possible.

Comment: Your view is rendered server-side, before the client-side code has a chance to run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a value to razor variable from javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317182/how-to-pass-a-value-to-razor-variable-from-javascript-variable)

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59973517/pass-object-type-as-parameter-in-javascript).  Please refrain from duplicating your questions.  You can edit it to provide more information, which will (probably) move it to the top of the home page.

Comment: Do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389649/possible-to-access-mvc-viewbag-object-from-javascript-file

Comment: @SteveGreene That's going the wrong direction, from Razor->JS.  This question is asking how to get a JS value into Razor, which cannot be done.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you need to get data server to client or vice versa there are techniques. Hidden fields come to mind.